# Why is my Ajax request significantly slower than a normal browser request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a website for a friend. Because he wished to have a music player continue to play music through page loads, I decided to load content into the page via ajax (facilitated by jQuery). It works fine, it falls back nicely when there is no javascript, and the back/forward buttons are working great, but it's dreadfully slow on the server.

A couple points:

1. The initial page load is fairly quick. The Chrome developer console tells me that "index.php" loads in about 2.5 seconds. I have it set up so that query string params dictate which page is loaded, and this time frame is approximately accurate for them all. For the homepage, there is 8.4KB of data loaded.
2. When I load the content in via an ajax request, no matter the size of the data downloaded, it takes approximately 20 seconds. The smallest amount of data that is loaded in this way is about 500 bytes. There is obviously a mismatch here.

So Chrome tells me that the vast majority of the time spent is "waiting" which I take to mean that the server is dealing with the request. So, that can only mean, I guess, that either my code is taking a long time, or something screwy is going on with the server. I don't think it's my code, because it's fairly minimal:

```
$file = "";
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $file = $_GET['page'];
} else if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
    $file = $_POST['page'];
} else {
    $file = "home";
}

$file = 'content/' . $file . '.php';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    include_once($file);
} else {
    include_once('content/404.php');
}
```

This is in a `content_loader.php` file which my javascript (in this scenario) sends a GET request to along with a "page" parameter. HTML markup is returned and put into a DIV on the page.

I'm using the `jQuery .get()` shorthand function, so I don't imagine I could be messing anything up there, and I'm confident it's not a Javascript problem because the delay is in waiting for the data from the server. And again, even when the data is very small, it takes about 20 seconds.

I currently believe it's a problem with the server, but I don't understand why a request made through javascript would be so much slower than a request made the traditional way through the browser. As an additional note, some of the content pages do connect to a MySQL database, but some do not. It doesn't seem to matter what the page requires for processing or how much data it consists of, it takes right around 20 seconds.

I'm at a loss... does anyone know of anything that might explain this? Also, I apologize if this is not the correct place for such a question, none of the other venues seemed particularly well suited for the question either.

Comment: There are a couple things that come to mind right away for me based on similar issues I've dealt with in the past. First thing is possibly a reverse DNS lookup issue. It could be timing out after failing on a reverse DNS lookup. Other questions: Are you using MySQL? Are you loading up a file-based session?

Comment: A MySQL connection is made, though some of the content pages don't use it at all. Also, I'm not using sessions at all. It just occurred to me to try and time the execution of my PHP, so I very simply echo'd out time() before anything else happened (including the connection to the database) and after everything was finished, just before it would be sent back to the client. The outputs were identical, so I assume that means my script takes less than a second to run. Could you talk more about the reverse DNS issue? I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: See my answer below. I just added a little more explanation.

Comment: My first suspicion would be your queries. I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out that your queries are really inefficient and are causing your application to wait while the database finishes execution.

Comment: @FeistyMango I don't think it's a query for two reasons. 1) He timed the PHP script execution itself and that was quick. Running a query would show up in the execution time - it's synchronous. 2) Queries are never that consistent, and if it's the same query it would be cached by the second time around.

Comment: @JustinWarkentin From what I read, to your first point my counter is this line: `When I load the content in via an ajax request, no matter the size of the data downloaded, it takes approximately 20 seconds.` What is going on during this 20 seconds? His test does not prove that it isnt spent at the db bc you are absolutely right, it is synchronous. to your second point: Queries can be very consistent depending on what it is your are talking about and if it is a shitty query with a large amount of data and bad indexing in the table, you'll get horrible execution time no matter what is cached.

Comment: In the second comment above he said "I very simply echo'd out time() before anything else happened (including the connection to the database) and after everything was finished, just before it would be sent back to the client. The outputs were identical" - if that is true then it's not the database, otherwise I would have suggested that MySQL could be waiting on a reverse DNS lookup as well - particularly if it's not hosted on the same server. I've had to deal  with that one too :) - So we actually know that it's a timeout and it's happening before any code is executed.

Comment: @JustinWarkentin Shame on me, I hadn't read that tid bit. That definitely makes the query theory doubtful.

Comment: @user2276673 One more question, what's your setup like exactly? Is there anything sitting between the computer you're requesting from and the server hosting the code (e.g. load balancer, firewall, etc...)? Also, is the MySQL server on the same system or are you making a connection to a remote MySQL server?

Comment: I should have mentioned. The site is on a shared server. That certainly makes looking into apache config files difficult! As well, the MySQL server is not local. However, I don't think this is a big problem because, again, it's taking no time at all to create that connection to the MySQL database. I've tried contacting the hosts support team, but that was quite useless, they simply repeated "There is no issue on our server." I decided, then, to ask here to see what the problem might be and if it might be my fault!

Comment: IK it's a bit old question, but I'm experiencing an identical problem. Let's say, I have page x. When I call it in browser - it's extremely fast, no time to load. When I call it in ajax - it's super slow. Maybe not beating OP's time (I get 5 secs), but still slow. I'm creating a map based game which I expect to be running fast... I'm using cross-domain ajax conmection with  CORS. (tho, both domains are controlled by me)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, a definite possibility could be reverse DNS lookups. I've had this problem before and I bet it's the source of your slow requests. There are certain Apache config directives you need to watch out for in both regular apache and vhost configs as well as `.htaccess`. Here are some links that should hopefully help:

http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2011/04/reverse_dns_lookups_and_apache/

http://betabug.ch/blogs/ch-athens/933

To find more resources just Google something like "apache slow reverse dns".

**A very little explanation**

In a reverse DNS lookup an attempt is made to resolve an IP address to a hostname. Most of the time with services like Apache, SSH and MySQL this is unnecessary and it's a bad idea as it only serves to slow down requests/connections. It's good to look for configuration settings for your different services and disable reverse DNS lookups if they aren't needed.

In Apache there are certain configuration settings that cause a reverse lookup to occur. Things like `HostnameLookups` and allow/deny rules specifying domains instead of IP addresses. See the links above for more info.

As you suggested in your comment, the PHP script is executing quickly once it finally runs. The time is spent waiting on Apache - most likely to do a reverse DNS lookup, and failing. You know the problem isn't with your code, it's with the other services involved in the request.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is my understanding that if a reverse DNS lookup was being made, then the apache access logs would show a hostname, as opposed to just an IP address, correct? In my case the logs are showing only an IP address.

Comment: It depends on what it's trying to do the lookup on. You may have HostnameLookups off, but a different rule elsewhere that tries to do it. Or, it could be failing on the reverse lookup and just sticking the IP in the logs. Try doing a reverse lookup on a recent IP in the logs here: http://remote.12dt.com/ - Also pay attention to the timestamp of the GET request in the access log versus the time you actually make the request, see what timestamp it's giving you.

Comment: The reverse lookup worked fine. I tested it on my IP address (which does show up in the logs of course) and it resolved to a sensible hostname. Another thing I don't understand is that it takes roughly 20 seconds every single time, it's as if the server is blocking for a period for some reason...

Comment: Yes, makes perfect sense. First, it's consistent in the amount of time it's waiting because it's waiting on a timeout. It still could be reverse DNS - not every reverse DNS request shows up in the logs. It also could be another service involved in the request - but I don't know what all you have setup or going on. Did you look at those links and look through your configs for other offending settings? Also, it would be very helpful to know what time Apache logs the request being received.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments to the original question, the site is on a shared server. For some reason, they aren't updating the logs in real time. They seem to update about every hour, which is quite annoying... I've saved the request time from my Javascript and I'll look at the log when it becomes available.